# How to postMessage to webview in Dart google chrome app (securityError)

Tags: webview, dart, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-webview

I'm building a Google Chrome App with webview using Dart programming language.
The app is communicating with webview content via postMessage. If I run the app from DartEditor (run as Chrome app) postMessage works ok. But after build (dart2js) and loading into browser with "Load unpackaged extention..." - application can't get webview contentWindow and execute postMessage on it.

Error from chrome dev console:
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://bpddihniogcgmnlaghkacfagkecgnljo" from accessing a frame with origin "swappedout://".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "chrome-extension", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "swappedout". Protocols must match.

Google Chrome Version 36.0.1951.5 dev
Dart version SDK 1.4.2, version 1.5.0-dev.4.2 - gives same error.

This is minimal working example to demonstrate the problem - https://github.com/Dumbris/dart_chrome_app_webview_security_error

Comment: There were several similar errors recently. I think you should file a bug report at dartbug.com/new

Comment: Added [Issue 19358](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19358)

Comment: I think you should answer your own question with a link to that issue, now that it is triaged. Don't flag it as accepted though until it's resolved.

Comment: It's a bit hackish, but you can run scripts (`webview.executeScript()`) to send messages to the webview, and use prompts to send a message from the webview to the app with the ability to retrieve a return value (`webview.addEventListener('dialog')`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It became known, this is a bug of current version of dart2js compiler, see [bug report here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19358)

I built a simple workaround [chromeapp_webview_wrapper.js](https://github.com/Dumbris/dart_chrome_app_webview_security_error/blob/workaround/web/chromeapp_webview_wrapper.js)
If contextWindow.postMessage called from JS wrapper - it works ok. 
Usage example:

```dart
js.JsObject _webview = new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(querySelector('webview'));
js.JsObject _webview_wrapper = new js.JsObject(js.context['WebviewWrapper'], [_webview]);
_webview_wrapper.callMethod('postMessage', ['initial message', '*']);
```

Nevertheless, I am waiting for bug fix from Dart developers team. Because, a communication with WebView content is significant function in Chrome Packaged App.